# Proper way to create multiple constructors with different parameters in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

Here is a look at my code, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. All I am trying to do is have 2 constructors, one with params and one without. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

The exact error that the compiler is throwing is :

```
      Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
          "Movie::Movie(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, 
        std::__1::allocator<char> >, int)", referenced from:
              _main in main-bc6b7c.o
          "Movie::Movie()", referenced from:
              _main in main-bc6b7c.o
        ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Trying too define my constructors in my header file.

```
        // Movie.h
    
        #include <string>
        #ifndef MOVIE_H
        #define MOVIE_H
        
        class Movie
        {
        private:
            int year;
            std::string title;
        
        public:
            Movie();
            Movie(std::string title, int year);
            std::string &getMovieTitle();
            int &getYear();
            void setMovieTitle(const std::string name);
            void setYear(const int year);
            void print();
            bool sameYear(Movie m);
        };
        
        #endif
```

Implementing my constructors in the cpp file.

```
        // Movie.cpp
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include "Movie.h"
        Movie::Movie()
        {
            this->year = 0;
            this->title = 'N/A';
        }
        
        Movie::Movie(std::string title, int year = 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Calling overloaded constructor" << std::endl;
            this->year = year;
            this->title = title;
        }
```

```
        //  main.cpp
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include "Movie.h"
    
        int main() {
           Movie movie1("Jurassic World", 2015);
    
           Movie movie2;
           return 0;
        }
```

Comment: How are you building (compiling and linking) your code?

Comment: Sure, I am using code runner on VS Code, and the exact command is:

cd "/Users/Jacob/Desktop/c++/module1_exercises/lab1/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/Jacob/Desktop/c++/module1_exercises/lab1/"main

Comment: @Jacob -- Nowhere in those commands do you specify `Movie.cpp` needs to be built.  The system doesn't automatically scan your directory for .cpp files -- you have to specify that they be built and part of the linking process.

Comment: Ok in the code runner docs it is supposed to auto build everything in the folder I run from, but I will add it manually thank you.

Comment: I have never used coderunner, but if that's the way it works, that IMO is a bad way to do things.  A C++ programmer would get frustrated knowing that their "dead" .cpp file that isn't supposed to be built actually becomes part of their program, all done behind their back.  That's why the programmer specifies all components that are part of the build, or the IDE they're using gives them the option to select the components for the build.